# Problems with an ImageJ plugin

Tags: linux, image-processing, imagej

I use the ImageJ as my default image viewer program. In order to view .nii format images, I installed the Nifti_io plugin following the instructions in [here](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/plugins/nifti.html)!

However, when I try to open an image from terminal, it just says

> File is not in a supported format, a reader plugin si not available, or it was not found. /tmp/TempFile-2805.nii

If I try to open the image just by clicking in ImageJ Plugins>Nifti Reader>/[imageURL] it opens it correctly, but I would like to open it directly from terminal.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Nifti_io plugin adds commands for importing but doesn't use the I/O plugin mechanism of ImageJ: [HandleExtraFileTypes](http://imagej.net/plugins/file-handler.html).

I would recommend [downloading Fiji](http://fiji.sc/Downloads) and giving it a try. It bundles a lot of useful ImageJ plugins, and the default `File > Open` will fall back to [Bio-Formats](http://www.openmicroscopy.org/site/products/bio-formats), which provides a [NiftiReader](https://github.com/openmicroscopy/bioformats/blob/a7c8d260c1ef7c29dfc282978ecea4c9b16893d5/components/formats-gpl/src/loci/formats/in/NiftiReader.java) implementation.

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me. I installed the HandleExtraFileTypes plugin and now it works perfectly