# Adding HandleExtraFileTypes to imageJ

Tags: ipython, imagej

I'm running SITK on ipython trying to get a handle on how it works and as part of it i'm trying to open an image by:

```
sitk.show(image)
```

But when imageJ opens I get this error: File is not in a supported format, a reader plugin is not available, or it was not found: 
/tmp/TempFile-142820.nii

I did a quick search and it looks like I need to add the HandleExtraFileTypes plugin, I've looked at [Problems with an ImageJ plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865762/problems-with-an-imagej-plugin) and http://imagej.net/plugins/file-handler.html but I can't figure out how to implement this plugin into imageJ. I can't seem to find a "plugins" folder for imageJ. I'm running all of this on a mac by the way.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After downloading the plugin file, in ImageJ plugin menu, pick install, select the file/folder you downloaded and ImageJ will install it (ImageJ finds the plugin folder for you here). Restart ImageJ and the plugin should work.