# Opening a .im files (nanoSIMS data) on FIJI using Macro

Tags: plugins, macros, imagej

I am looking for a macro command to open .im files in FIJI.

Since FIJI does not support the .im format, it requires a plugin called OpenMIMS, but simple lines:

```bs
run("Open MIMS Image"); 
open(" directory ");
```

would give an error message:

> File is not in a supported format, a reader plugin is not available, or it was not found.

An almost the same question has apparently been asked and solved here-
[Problems with an ImageJ plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865762/problems-with-an-imagej-plugin/25891192#25891192), except I am already using FIJI and Bio-Formats would not be a solution to my problem as it does not seem to support .im files, either.

I would much appreciate it if someone could enlighten me. =)

Answer (score 2):

You should first check whether you can open the file using the menu via *Plugins > Open MIMS Image*. (I assume you installed the OpenMIMS plugin [according to these instructions](http://nrims.partners.org/wiki/index.php/Installation), adding an update site.)

When you do this while the [macro recorder](http://imagej.net/Introduction_into_Macro_Programming#The_recorder) is running, it should record the necessary command to use in your macro code.

In the lines you posted, the second line:

```
open(" directory ");
```

doesn't make any sense and by itself will result in the error message you posted (have a look at the second part of the error message to find out the path that ImageJ is trying to open).